# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: api.users

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-testing

I am trying to write a simple **unittest** case for my app but it crashes after the first test with error:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: api.users
```

Below is my test case (I use **Flask-Testing**):

```
class RestApiTestCase(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app = create_app('config.testing')
        self.client = app.test_client()
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        self.db = DAO(db)
        init_db(db)

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        drop_db(db)
        self.db = None
```

I didn't post tests because of it doesn't play any role, it always completes the first test and crashes on the next.
I tried to call `app_context.push()` on `setUp` and `app_context.pop()` on `tearDown` but it didn't help, I tried to use simple **unittest** and it still fails.

Where can problem be? I use **blueprint** and **Flask-RESTful** in my app, should I unbind it manually on shutting down app event?